# How to design a recommendation page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ive got an app that allows users to listen to music. Each artist has a specific genre set for him/herself. The songs don't have genres.

I need a recommendation page based on what song genre the user looks at from time to time.

Consider this example.

Ive got: 
User Joe
Artist Ben. Has genre acoustic. Has 1 song.
Artist Alex. Has genre jazz, has 1 song.
Artist Hannah. Has genre acoustic. Has 1 song.

User Joe listens to Alex's song twice and listens to Ben's song 3 times. In the recommendation page, it should show Ben and Hannah. Since Joe likes listening to acoustic media more.

How should I go about designing this? Should I have a table that keeps track this data? If so, what columns should exist?

Or, should I do some kind of aggregation when the recommendation page is loaded instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a has_many through join between songs and users. This join would in addition to the user_id and song_id have a listens counter. Then you can find users who have listened to the same songs as the individual user, return the songs those users have listened to most and ordered by those users first who have the same genre then those who do not.